# Possible to create junction links in C:\windows?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, ssd

Is safe to junction link folders in C:\windows ? I'm trying to micromanage and fine tune so that large files that are infrequently accessed are offloaded away from the SSD.

I wouldn't dream of doing this in my primary workstation, however this can makes sense for Virtual Machines. I have a VM I just created, Windows 7, and the Windows Folder is approximately 15 gigabytes. I would like to move non critical pieces of this folder via junction links (which point to another virtual hard drive letter that sits on a mechanical disk on the host).

And so:

1) (a) Which pieces (if any, or all) of C:\windows can be junction-linked to another hard disk, without creating problems?

(b) If applicable, which folders are most rarely needed in C:\windows for day to day?
[image: Windows 7 Folder Size Composition, For Convenience]

Answer (score 0):

> (b) If applicable, which folders are most rarely needed in C:\windows for day to day?

You can safely delete the folder named *SoftwareDistribution*. To do this use `net stop wuauserv`, then delete everything in the folder.  If you want you can also delete WindowsUpdate.log. Then restart the update service with `net start wuauserv`. This will repopulate the softwaredistribution folder with a few files.

An other folder you might not need but which makes **no** sense to move is the winsxs. A large part of the content in that folder already are hardlinks/junctions.

As for part a) of your question: I never tried doing this with the OS files. If it is setup in a sane way then I *guess* (repeat: guess) that you could move any files which are loaded after the filesystem drivers are loaded.

---

When I create virtual machines I usually install from the most modern version of the OS because somehow those end up using less disc space.

Example:

- Install 1: Fresh windows 7 install, all windows updates.Window build in disk clean. Installed and an ccleaner. Removed ccleaner. Removed all restore points.
- Install 2: Fresh windows 7 SP 1install, all windows updates.Window build in disk clean. Installed and an ccleaner. Removed ccleaner. Removed all restore points.

Install 1 used 1.8GB more space. (12.4GB vs 10.6GB)
Hardware used was identical (a vmware host with the same settings).